# Difference between these two sentences?

Tags: differences

"How do I suppose to have a garden at home?"

"How am I supposed to have a garden at home?"

Is there any differences?

Comment: The idiom is _How `be X` supposed to `VP`?_: _How am I supposed to know, How were they supposed to manage it,_ etc. The _supposed to_ part is pronounced /spost/, never /spozd/. It's always a question, and it's a rhetorical question because the answer is that `X` is or was **not** in fact sposta.

Comment: I don't know what "How do I suppose to have a garden at home?" means, if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a world of difference; the first "I" is the subject, in the second ,it is equivalent to saying "How do people suppose that I ...", The second is correct.